# How to convert german undergrad grade to US GPA

Tags: grades, gpa

How am I supposed to provide US Universities during my application process a GPA if there is no official way to convert a 1.6 (German grade) to US GPA ?

I have tried to find a ressource but every website sais something else and there is no official conversion table.

Do the admission offices calculate it anyways on their own (based on transcripts) or how does it work?

Comment: Ask your registrar if they have some sort of "explanation of grades" document that they send along with transcript requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can always call the school to find out.  I'm sure you won't be the first foreign student to have applied.  That said, it looks like Wikipedia has a pretty good page on how to convert, and your score should be somewhere in the 3.75 range or so.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_Germany

You'll have to go course by course to find the right number.  Good luck!

Comment: The article seems very vague. Even though that it looks like a lot of information. WES for example grades completeley different. Yes of course, the school will of course now but thought somebody here might know how it works

Comment: Well so it contains enough information for you to take all of the grades you received in Germany, convert them to American grades, and then add them up and divide by the total number of courses which gives you an American GPA.  I don't know if there's a quicker way to do that, but that will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an American who got my MSc in Germany so I've had to do this both ways. It's a pain. I know for employment in the US (if I use my MSc to try and get a job etc), the US Department of Education requires you to hire a company to do this. It typically costs a few hundred dollars and I suspect you'll have to do this at some point anyway to get into a US school. There is a list of companies "recognized" by the Department of Education available on [this page] (https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ous/international/usnei/us/edlite-visitus-forrecog.html).

I also found this chart on [this page](https://welcometogermerica.com/2015/07/american-to-german-grade-conversion.html). It's less official and you'll probably need an official transcript evaluation anyway, but here's a quick one:

[German to US Grades](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcCax.png)

**So your 1.6 would be about (slightly higher than) a 3.6.**