# UK Grading to US GPA conversion

Tags: gpa

I analysed admission requirements for Master course in the US university and found that one of them is GPA from an undergraduate course.

I am studying Electrical and Electronic Engineering at the University of Manchester in the United Kingdom where the final grade is composed of the second and the third-year grades.

In more detail, the first year does not count towards the final grade, the second year makes 25% of the final grade and the third year contributes to the 75% of the final grade. Each year contains 120 credits split between modules and marks for each module are given in percentage.

Could you please tell how my GPA, scaled from 0 to 4, would be calculated in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The Admissions department of the institute you apply to will do their own “conversion” as they see fit using the courses or modules they consider relevant or they wish to “credit”...

Trying to predict what and how they convert - well you probably have more chance at the lottery...

See this other answer : [How to convert german undergrad grade to US GPA](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/75355/72855)